# Sum Totals for Every 1/2 Hour

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 columns: [StartDT] and [EndDT], they are datetime format like such: 2014-05-20 12:45:18.383

I need to get things in terms of total sum of the difference between [StartDT] and [EndDT] every 1/2 hour.  So basically each row of my output would be the sum of the differences for a particular 1/2 period like:  00:00 - 34 Seconds, next row: 00:30 - 23 Seconds.

I was able to create the code to do this once and it looks like this:

```
 SELECT  sum(DATEDIFF ( s , [StartDT] , [EndDT] )) as SumTotal
 FROM [Radio].[dbo].[Sheet1]
 WHERE DATEPART(DAY, StartDT) = 1 and DATEPART(HOUR, StartDT) between 0 and 1 and DATEPART(MI, StartDT) between 0 and 30;
```

The code will look at the table and find the first 30 minute period of the first hour of the first day.  Now how would I automate this to iterate through the entire table. I know how I would do it in C, but I do not have much experience with SQL for sub quires or Common Table Expressions (CTE) .

Comment: My preference here is a dimension table...create a table called dim_time or something to that extent and populate with every 30 minute interval that you wish to report on.  You can cross join a list of dates to this and have a resulting table with a 48 timeslots of 30 mins for each day.  You then use that table as the starting point for your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is calculating your `HalfHour` value, then `GROUP BY` - try:

```
SELECT dateadd(mi, (datediff(mi, 0, StartDT) / 30) * 30, 0) as HalfHour
       , sum(DATEDIFF ( s , [StartDT] , [EndDT] )) as SumTotal
FROM Radio.dbo.Sheet1
GROUP BY dateadd(mi, (datediff(mi, 0, StartDT) / 30) * 30, 0) 
ORDER BY 1
```